# mySQL ODBC connection string for 64bit on VB6.0

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have a program in visual basic 6.0 that uses MySQL ODBC connection I have installed MySQL ODBC connector 5.2.7  64-bit but when ever i try to connect with my datasource it says

**[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application**

Is there any way to edit my connection string to work on 64 bit or any other solution to resolve this error? here is my code:

```
Public Function dbclose()
On Error Resume Next
    ac.Close
    Set ac = Nothing
    ar.Close
    Set ar = Nothing
End Function
Public Sub openDB()
Dim connect As String

connect = "Provider=MSDataShape.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=LSRS;Data Provider=MSDASQL"
strConek = "Provider=MSDataShape.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=LSRS;Data Provider=MSDASQL"

With con
    .Open connect
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
 End With
End Sub

Public Function dbuser()
Set ac = New ADODB.Connection
Set ar = New ADODB.Recordset
strConek = "Provider=MSDataShape.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=LSRS;Data Provider=MSDASQL"
End Function

Public Function dbconek()
    Set ac = New ADODB.Connection
    Set ar = New ADODB.Recordset
strConek = "Provider=MSDataShape.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=LSRS;Data Provider=MSDASQL"
End Function
```

Comment: Is your Visual Basic application compiled as a 64-bit application ?

Comment: nope but all things work fine to me, I was using the same version on windows XP 32 bit

Comment: Which database do you use, mysql or ms sql?

Comment: You need a 32bit driver; a 32bit process cannot make use of a 64bit driver irrespective of the machine/os architecture.

Comment: @Shadow I am using mysql

Comment: I agree with @AlexK, that is exactly what the error message is telling you. It might have worked on Windows XP 32 bit because you were using a 32 bit ODBC driver.

Comment: @AlexK. I have installed both drivers 32 and 64 but didn't work for me

Comment: The connections strings you provided were for ms sql, hence the question. You should reference mysql odbc driver directly.