# MySQL Connector for VB6 and run it in win10

Tags: mysql, vb6, connector

Several years ago I built an app with vb6 with mysql. It ran on win 7 32. I used ADODC to connect with MySQL. Nothing happens until the boss said it's time to change old machine and run win 10. How can I run my app in win 10 with mysql? The app is run well, but I can't connect to mySQL.

when MySQL Connector 64 installed, it said something like different architecture etc...
Help me...what should I do?

Comment: VB6 is 32bit only. perhaps that is the problem

Comment: I agree with @froque.  Here is the same issue for your reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909610/mysql-odbc-connection-string-for-64bit-on-vb6-0